# How can i make image size big using css?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make image size big but it is not happening with below code, How can i achieve that task using css ? Do i need to overwrite bootstrap ?

```css
#logo {
  height: 40px;
}
.navbar-brand>img {
  max-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -o-object-fit: contain;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<a class="navbar-brand">
  <img src="assets/images/logo.png" id="logo">
</a>
```

Comment: So what isn't working you are setting a height of 40px for the img ...

Comment: height is not working

Comment: With the code you provide is working https://jsfiddle.net/vjxxodzq/

Comment: Check your developer tools if other css rules are overriding your rule

Comment: The image height is going to the height of ID on the image `#logo` which is `40px` you can change the height of this and it will make the logo taller. If you remove the height it should display the actual size of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
img.expand { width: 10em; }
```

```html
<img src="http://keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg" alt="fruit" class="expand" />
```

or

```css
img.expand { width: 50em; }
```

```html
<img src="http://keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg" alt="fruit" class="expand" />
```

Comment: You can increase/decrease image size using by width:10em/50em increase/decrease.